# ojdbc14.jar for Oracle 12c supported?

Tags: java, oracle, oracle12c

We have application developed in portlet Factory 5.1 which is using Oracle 9i. we are using ojdbc14.jar for that. we are upgrading the Oracle from 9i to 12c. is this ojdbc.jar supported for Oracle 12c as well? i believe it is compatible. Any Idea?

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_03

Answer (score 4):

It is better to use the `ojdbc7.jar` as oracle suggest it in their [supports list](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/default-2280470.html).

Also the jar version corresponds to the `jdbc` version that your j2ee comprises of . So i guess you wont be having any issues with the database upgrade.

But remember you may get the support for  only `ojdbc7.jar` on using `12c Release`, it is better to upgrade it!